# GitHub Actions: How to run code from different branches on schedule?

Tags: github, github-actions

I have two branches i.e. `main` and `develop`. I want to run code with GitHub Actions for branch `main` (Production) and for `develop` (Staging) on schedule (nightly).

I've read that the workflow schedule can only be configured for the default branch on GitHub. So, what implementation for the `workflow.yaml` would be?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, according to [schedule](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#schedule):

> Scheduled workflows run on the latest commit on the default or base branch.

However, it looks like it's doable by configuring the cron job for the default branch and then somehow triggering the workflow for the non-default branch e.g. [using the GitHub API or CLI](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#workflow_dispatch).

See [workflow_dispatch](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#workflow_dispatch) for more details.

Or, via [workflow_run](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#workflow_run) configuration after completion of the workflow on the default branch. Though, in this case, you might not want to combine both in general scenarios.

Comment: Unintentionally found the solution:
Use checkout action and **ref** tag
steps:
      - name: Tests checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          ref: main

Comment: @Martix: Isn't `main` your default branch? What about `develop`?

Comment: The default is main but for running codebase from develop, i 've created another workflow file with such a construction "uses: actions/checkout@v3
with:
  ref: develop"

Comment: @Martix: So, you pushed the workflow to the `main` branch and configured it to run for the `develop` branch, right?